# Is it true that $\sum_{i=1}^n \big|f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big| \leq \sum_{i=1}^n\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|$ on expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, absolute-value

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables, and $f,g$ two functions. I am wondering whether the following result holds

$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \big|f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big|\right]
\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\right].
$$

My derivation is as follows. Start by defining $\epsilon$ as

$$\epsilon = \sum_{i=1}^n \big|f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big|.$$

Now, it is clear that

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[\epsilon]
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big|\Big] \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i) + g(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big|\Big].
\end{align}
$$

For simplicity, define $\delta_i \equiv f(X_i) - g(X_i) + g(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]$ and replace above:

$$
  \mathbb{E}[\epsilon]
  = \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\big[|\delta_i|\big]
  = \sum_{i:\:\delta_i \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big]
    - \sum_{i:\:\delta_i < 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big].
$$

Since $\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big] = \mathbb{E}\big[f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big] \leq \mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big]$, we get

$$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[\epsilon]
  &= \sum_{i:\:\delta_i \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big]
    - \sum_{i:\:\delta_i < 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big]   \\
  &\leq \sum_{i:\:\delta_i \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big]
     + \sum_{i:\:\delta_i < 0}\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big] \\
  &= \sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big] \\
  &= \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\right].
\end{align}
$$

Putting everything together, we can conclude that

$$
\mathbb{E}[\epsilon] = \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n \big|f(X_i) - \mathbb{E}[g(X_i)]\big|\right]
\leq \mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\right].
$$

It sounds like it should not be true, but I am not sure where I might have gone wrong.

Comment: $$
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[\epsilon]
  &= \sum_{i:\:\delta_i \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big]
    - \sum_{i:\:\delta_i < 0}\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big]   \\
  &\leq \sum_{i:\:\delta_i \geq 0}\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big]
     + \sum_{i:\:\delta_i < 0}\mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big] 
\end{align}$$ is wrong. You need  a bound on $E|\delta_i|$ for this.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I guess the problem would be with the line

$$
\mathbb{E}\big[\delta_i\big] = \mathbb{E}\big[f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big] \leq \mathbb{E}\Big[\big|f(X_i) - g(X_i)\big|\Big].
$$

Is that correct?

Comment: The RHS of the inequality makes no sense. You have taken the expectation inside the sum, (so that what remains is a constant, not a random variable), but the indices subsets are still random.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Thanks!

Comment: A counterexample is $n=1,f=2g,$ for some $g$ such that $E(g(X))=0$ and $E(|g(X)|)\ne0.$